# generic type erasure ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics

```
package practice;

class Node<T> {

    T data;

    public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    @Override
    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] s)
    {
        MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
        Node n = mn;            // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
        n.setData("Hello");     // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
        Integer x = mn.data;    
    }
}
```

Why does this code throw exception at `n.setData("Hello");` when actually it should throw the exception at `Integer x = mn.data;`?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a small mistake in the tutorial: they should have said that the error is thrown at line `n.setData("Hello");`

That's because when you call `n.setData("Hello");` you call the bridge method: `n.setData(Object object)` **on `MyNode`** class, otherwise you would have a compile time error.

But the bridge method looks like this:

```
// Bridge method generated by the compiler
//
public void setData(Object data) {
    setData((Integer) data);
}
```

You see that the bridge tries to invoke the `setData(Integer anInt)` with a cast on the `data`. And this cast fails because you provided a `String`.

What's also interesting at this example is that you get no compile time error when using `@Override` annotation even that you technically don't override, but the compiler overrides later. The annotation is very very useful here to inform that the `setData(Object object)` will be called on `MyNode` not on `Node`. This explains why you don't see any of the `System.out` messages.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to set String value to Integer variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have already defined the type `T` for `Node` by calling

```
MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
```

namely `Integer` type. By calling `n.setData("Hello");` you are attempting to pass in a String variable for an Integer field. Node `n` is merely a reference for the `Integer` typed Node `mn`.

Comment: Interesting, some code on that page doesn't even compile, e.g. `Integer x = (String)mn.data;` However once the type is defined, you can't 'shoehorn' in another.

Answer (score 0):

Because the type of `n` is actually `Integer`, which it received from `mn`.

It's the same principle as `List list = new ArrayList();`

The list here is actually an `ArrayList`, but only referenced using the List interface. Similarly, even though `n` is a `Node`, it's implementation is a `MyNode` which only accepts `Integer`. That's why you can put a `String` in `setData()`

**After reading the edit example**

The page says that a bridge method is created as follows :

```
class MyNode extends Node {

    // Bridge method generated by the compiler
    //
    public void setData(Object data) {
        setData((Integer) data);
    }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The bridge method does the following

```
public void setData(Object data) {
            setData((Integer) data);
        }
```

Here it is trying to cast data which is the `String` "Hello" into an `Integer`. Hence the error is thrown.